# data-attributes and a bad logic (my logic)

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I would like to use data-attributes on a a project , but seems that my logic isn't logic...

so , this is what I am trying :

http://jsfiddle.net/vPh7S/

and this is my logic in the jquery:

```
var a = $('#haus').find('article');
var haus = $('#haus');


function startBubbles() {
    var item = a;
    var dataId = item.data('id');
    var dataTop = item.data('data-top');
    var dataDuration = item.data('data-duration');

    $(dataId).animate({
        top: dataTop
    }, dataDuration);

    // $('#a1').animate({top:'5%'},500,'easeOutBounce');
    // $('#a2').animate({top:'50%'},550,'easeOutBounce');
    // $('#a3').animate({top:'50%'},600,'easeOutBounce');
    // $('#a4').animate({top:'60%'},650,'easeOutBounce');
    // $('#a5').animate({top:'80%'},700,'easeOutBounce');
    // $('#a6').animate({top:'26%'},750,'easeOutBounce');

}

startBubbles();
```

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: Your CSS is not valid, you can't nest CSS declarations in pure CSS.

Comment: my CSS, is SCSS, super standard for my workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/vPh7S/2/

```
function startBubbles() {
    $('#haus > article').each(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            top: parseInt($(this).data('top'))
    }, $(this).data('duration'));
});
startBubbles();
```

You were using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function wrong. It already knows there's a `data-` prefix so it works like this: `$('#id').data('top')` instead of `$('#id').data('data-top')`.

You were also selecting multiple elements (`<article>`) but treating them as one. I used the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to go through each element and animate it how you intended.

Comment: Thanks , I don't even know that parseInt exist ! , 

one last doubt, why is printing in data-top px instead of % ?

Comment: Oh! I see, the problem was that we are using parseInit , so if I remove the chain , then it will print the complete string.

Thanks Again @Joe

Comment: Yes, sorry. I put in `parseInt()` so that it would show the code was working. Removing it properly adds `X%` as the style.